# Testing if ASP Table is Visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I know this is going to be such a simple solution, but for some reason I cannot get this method to work in C#.  I simply want to do a Boolean test to see if an ASP table is visible.  If so, set visible to false, else set visible to true.

What would be the correct syntax for this test?

```
protected void btnNewMaterial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tblMaterialDetails.Visible==true)
    {
        this.tblMaterialDetails.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.tblMaterialDetails.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

On a supplemental note, I am running ASP 4.5

Comment: whats happening now? Can you post the control code?

Comment: Did you actually try this code? Did it not work as expected?

Comment: you are probably running into `PostBack` issue are you familiar with PostBacks and how to use the debugger..? you're probably setting it and when the postback happens it's setting it back to true in regards to the Visible

Comment: Yes, of course I tested the code before posting.  When stepping through line-by-line, the Boolean test always returns false, even though the object property shows true.

Comment: Why in some cases are you using `tblMaterialDetails.Visible` and other cases `this.tblMaterialDetails.Visible`?

Comment: I come from the land of VBA, so ASP.NET are still new to me.  Thank you @MethodMan for not being a troll.  I'll read up on postbacks and see if that gets me any closer to my goal.

Comment: You can simply do tblMaterialDetails.Visible = !tblMaterialDetails.Visible;

As @MethodMan mentioned, you might be running into PostBack issue. Are you setting any visibility of table in Page_Load event?

Comment: No one here is trolling you. There's just a higher expectation of you than what you believe. You posted some code but didn't explain how it wasn't working. You should have provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clearly explained the behavior you are expecting and the behavior you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: as mentioned in comments you do not need to write this codes for such a simple action. It is enough `tblMaterialDetails.Visible = !tblMaterialDetails.Visible;`

Second: Your code is true and it is impossible that not work. So check some things, Maybe you removed `OnClick="btnNewMaterial_Click"` in your button. And if in debug mode you see method fires, Probably you have some directions about table visibility in your **Page_Load**. One thing that some times is forgotten is that: **Page_Load works after Button_Click**

Comment: Thank you for the tip!  I didn't realize the Page_Load event fired every time I hit the Button_Click event.  I just made the assumption that that it worked liked the Form_Load event in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the result that you need

```
bool isVisible = tblMaterialDetails.Visible;
```

it will tell if it is or is not visible so your if condition could be

```
if (tblMaterialDetails.Visible)
{
   // your code here
}
```